# Android service-to-activity communication at high frequency: best option?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

In an Android app (API level 14 and higher), which has a service used by different activities (they call its functions using a local binding), the service computes a position (coordinates) of a game-element at 60 Hz. [I have good reasons to do the computations in the service and not just in the activities directly]. These continuous position updates are required in the service (for game-logic checks) AND in the playscreen activities (for drawing).

My question to you is: what is the option to choose for service-to-activity communication for this scenario? I'd like to minimize the delay in milliseconds (at best, virtually no delay at all) between the point of time the service computed a fresh location, and the point when it is known to the UI (Activity).

You can assume that everything (activities, service) is in one process.

I was thinking about a solution where each activity, whenever it resumes, tells the service about its existence (and in onPause() the activities tell the service about their unavailability), so that the service, when it computed new coordinates, can simply check whether an activity is visible, and if it is, call visibleActivity.someMethod() directly.
It is understood that .someMethod() internally hands control over to the UI thread.

I propose this, because I'm sure that going via Broadcasts should kill performance.

Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: FYI you should look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html if you don't have to get results back.

Comment: What I hate about broadcasting in general, is that you have to write a lot of boilerplate code. E.g. if I want to call `activity.someMethod()`, I really have to create an intent, put some key/value pair in it as extra that says which method I actually want to call, and then on the receiver side (BroadcastReceiver) I have to do string-comparisons. That seems just ugly and unnecessary to me..

Answer (score 3):

Your activities should register listeners implemented in [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) with the service and the service should maintain them in a [RemoteCallbackList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RemoteCallbackList.html)

Your service should have two methods like this to be called by your Activities in onResume/onPause

```
public void registerListener(IYourListenerInterface listener) {
     callbackList.register(listener);
}


public void unregisterListener(IYourListenerInterface listener) {
     callbackList.unregister(listener);
}
```

When you need to send a message:

```
int numOfListeners = callbackList.beginBroadcast();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfListeners; i++) {
    try {
        callbackList.getBroadcastItem(i).whatever();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        //ignore, listener probably gone
    }
}
callbackList.finishBroadcast();
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the example. I assume the purpose of calling `beginBroadcast()` and `finishBroadcast()` is to make `registerListener()` and `unregisterListener()` block, while an execution of (`someInterface.doSomething()`) is running?

Comment: Btw, I just understood that this actually uses `IInterface`. I suppose what this means is that the methodology of locally binding a service (to an activity) is just used the other way round (locally binding an activity to a service). And then `RemoteCallbackList` makes sure to properly manage which local bindings are available at any given time.

Comment: If your service and activities are in the same process, than they share the same main application thread.  If you make your callbacks from the main thread, you should be assured that your activities cannot register/unregister during this time because onResume and onPause are always called during it.  And yes, your interface needs to inherit from IInterface.

Comment: OK, but what should implementing activities of such an IInterface return in `asBinder()`?

Comment: Implement your interface in [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) and the SDK will take care of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Oh. Well, I was rather hoping for a solution that does NOT use AIDL. AFter all, I'm not using the AIDL-specific features (I do NOT want IPC at all).

Comment: You don't really need to have IPC to use AIDL.  In reality, you could just pass around objected directly since they're in the same process, but be very careful of leaking an Activity/Service.

Comment: Yes, regarding the leaking, I originally posted "...each activity, whenever it resumes (in `onResume()`), tells the service about its existence (and in onPause() the activities tell the service about their unavailability)". That should be enough, right?

Comment: IMHO, there is no need for AIDL if they are in a same process. Messinger / Broadcast reciever will do the job here

Answer (score 1):

I would use `LocalBroadcastManager`, or possibly [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/). These offer better component decoupling than the solution already presented (binding and callbacks). This is important, as activities can come and go based upon user action (configuration changes, BACK button).

> I have good reasons to do the computations in the service and not just in the activities directly

To be honest, I can't imagine what those reasons would be.

Comment: How does Otto do the communication internally? I'm afraid that even LocalBroadcastManager will produce too much overhead for 60 Hz service-to-activity communication. The reasons why computations are (also) necessary in the service is because of game logic checks. I don't want the UI to be anything else than a stupid visualization of what is going on, so I would never put any gamelogic there.

Comment: @NameZero912: "How does Otto do the communication internally?" -- you would have to look at its implementation. "I'm afraid that even LocalBroadcastManager will produce too much overhead for 60 Hz service-to-activity communication" -- not by a few orders of magnitude IMHO. "so I would never put any gamelogic there" -- but that does not explain why it needs to be in a service versus a POJO.

Comment: Regarding "but that does not explain why it needs to be in a service versus a POJO": Actually, I have a component dealing with networking (since it's a multiplayer game). This one has to be in a service, as it should also work even if no activities are visible (especially for the device hosting the game). There is bi-directional communication between Networking and my GameLogic component, which needs to be as low-delay as possible. Similarly, there is communication between GameLogic and visible activities. There is also some communication between networking and activities, but I don't...

Comment: ...require them to have low latency. So, that's why I thought that GameLogic and Networking should be in the service together, and can efficiently communicate with each other using normal POJO references. I could use Otto for communication from service classes to activities, and use service-binding to communicate from activities to service. I am strictly against the bollocks of implementing generation of intents (even for one-to-one communication). It seems unfathomably stupid to me that one has to invent strings to be compared and placed as intent-extras, just to have method calls this way.

Comment: @NameZero912 the thing that u put heavy calculations in service doesn't mean u release UI thread from it.. Especially when service is not remote but local..